# Multiple upload and resize class.upload.php

Tags: php, upload, resize, image-resizing

I'm trying to upload multiple image to the server and to make different resolution version of each image.
To do this I'm using class.upload.php for the first time. http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

I look at the documentation and starting from the demo example http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_download_zip.htm

I made a form with multiple input

```
<form name="form3" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
   <p><input type="file" size="32" name="my_field[]" value="" /></p>
   <p><input type="file" size="32" name="my_field[]" value="" /></p>
   <p><input type="file" size="32" name="my_field[]" value="" /></p>
   <p><input type="file" size="32" name="my_field[]" value="" /></p>
   <p><input type="file" size="32" name="my_field[]" value="" /></p>
   <p class="button"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="multiple" />
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload" /></p>
</form>
```

the original php from the example only upload the image without resizing them:

```
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['my_field'] as $k => $l) {
    foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
            $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
}

// now we can loop through $files, and feed each element to the class
foreach ($files as $file) {

    // we instanciate the class for each element of $file
    $handle = new Upload($file);

    // then we check if the file has been uploaded properly
    // in its *temporary* location in the server (often, it is /tmp)
    if ($handle->uploaded) {

        // now, we start the upload 'process'. That is, to copy the uploaded file
        // from its temporary location to the wanted location
        // It could be something like $handle->Process('/home/www/my_uploads/');
        $handle->Process($dir_dest);

        // we check if everything went OK
        if ($handle->processed) {
            // everything was fine !
            echo 'ok';
        } else {
            // one error occured
            echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '';
        }

    } else {
        // if we're here, the upload file failed for some reasons
        // i.e. the server didn't receive the file
        echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '';
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to process each file inside the if ($handle->processed) {} 
so I took the function form the example that resize img and paste it inside the  if ($handle->processed) {} part. Now it  look like this:

```
if ($handle->uploaded) {

        // now, we start the upload 'process'. That is, to copy the uploaded file
        // from its temporary location to the wanted location
        // It could be something like $handle->Process('/home/www/my_uploads/');
        // now, we start a serie of processes, with different parameters
        // we use a little function TestProcess() to avoid repeting the same code too many times
        function TestProcess(&$handle, $title) {
            global $dir_pics, $dir_dest;

            $handle->Process($dir_dest);

            // we check if everything went OK
            if ($handle->processed) {
                // everything was fine !
                echo 'ok';
            } else {
                // one error occured
                echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '';
           }
        }
        if (!file_exists($dir_dest)) mkdir($dir_dest);

        // ----------- save the uploaded img adding _xl to the name
        $handle->file_name_body_add    = '_xl';
        $handle->file_overwrite = true;
        TestProcess($handle, 'File originale', '');

        // ----------- save the uploaded img adding _l to the name and downsizing it
        $handle->file_name_body_add    = '_l';
        $handle->image_resize          = true;
        $handle->image_ratio_y         = true;
        $handle->image_x               = 1024;
        $handle->file_overwrite = true;
        TestProcess($handle, 'Ridimensionato a 1024px');
    }
```

At this point the script works fine only with the first img.
it not make the "foreach ($files as $file)" trow the $files array... 
could you help my find where the error is?
thaks
Daniele

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creator of the class here... You need to change the $files array first, as following. It is in the [FAQ](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_faq.htm):

```
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['my_field'] as $k => $l) {
 foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
 if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
   $files[$i] = array();
   $files[$i][$k] = $v;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I made a form with 10 input to load multiple image
Now I can upload and resize 2 images, but if I insert a 3rd one in the form this is uploaded but not resized and no image after the 3rd is processed... I really don't understand why! here you can find the script I made starting from the documentation http://www.danielepennati.com/prove/upload_php/index.html

Comment: Does not seem to work for me... i get so many errors, and i have so many problems when trying to use this class.

Feel like shitting myself cause of all the time I've spend on this... boss not happy


Notice: Undefined index: tmp_name in /home/webstarters/admin/public_html/backend/components/helpers/uploadHelper.php on line 2361

Notice: Undefined index: size in /home/webstarters/admin/public_html/backend/components/helpers/uploadHelper.php on line 2379

Notice: Undefined index: type in /home/webstarters/admin/public_html/backend/components/helpers/uploadHelper.php on line 2380.

Comment: I need to be able to use image_field[], i dont understand how you can create such a big class without handling image arrays -.-

When i find the solution can we somehow implement it in the class so others dont get these problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i tried to use verot's answer but i got ALOT of errors, i tried other answers around the web.

Here is the working solution.

```
$placeDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myuploadfolder';

$files = [];
foreach ($_FILES['image_field']['name'] as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($_FILES['image_field']['name'][$key])){
        $name  = $_FILES['image_field']['name'][$key];
        $type  = $_FILES['image_field']['type'][$key];
        $tmp   = $_FILES['image_field']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $error = $_FILES['image_field']['error'][$key];
        $size  = $_FILES['image_field']['size'][$key];
        $files[] = [
              'name'     => $name
            , 'type'     => $type
            , 'tmp_name' => $tmp
            , 'error'    => $error
            , 'size'     => $size
        ];
    }
}

foreach($files as $file){
    $image = new uploadHelper($file);
    $image->allowed = array('image/*');
    if ($image->uploaded) {
      $image->process($placeDir);
      if ($image->processed) {
        echo 'image done';
        $image->clean();
      } else {
        echo 'error : ' . $image->error;
      }
    } else {
        echo '<h1>IMAGE NOT UPLOADED</H1>';
    }
}
```

I really hope this helps people out there.